# join of large tables with primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The table `mydat` has around `48.3M` records with definition:

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┐
│     Column     │     Type     │ Modifiers │
├────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────┤
│ id             │ bigint       │ not null  │
│ dt             │ integer      │ not null  │
│ data           │ real         │           │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┘
Indexes:
    "mydat_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, dt)
```

For each object as identified by `id`, there are about 40 records as denoted by the `dt` time field. The goal is to check the variation pattern between successive records, and the implementation is to join each record with its next one based on `dt` for each `id`. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mydat AS dat1
  JOIN mydat AS dat2
    ON dat1.id = dat2.id
   AND dat1.dt = dat2.dt - 1;
```

The query plan is given below. *Merge-Join* is used, and it took forever to run. Also, we can see that the row count `427198811` is seriously over-estimated. Seems postgresql does not take the uniqueness of `(id,dt)` into consideration.

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                          QUERY PLAN                                           │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Merge Join  (cost=19919125.46..25466155.03 rows=247144681 width=222)                          │
│   Merge Cond: ((dat1.id = dat2.id) AND (dat1.dt = ((dat2.dt - 1))))                           │
│   ->  Sort  (cost=9959562.73..10080389.92 rows=48330876 width=111)                            │
│         Sort Key: dat1.id, dat1.dt                                                            │
│         ->  Seq Scan on mydat dat1  (cost=0.00..982694.76 rows=48330876 width=111)            │
│   ->  Materialize  (cost=9959562.73..10201217.11 rows=48330876 width=111)                     │
│         ->  Sort  (cost=9959562.73..10080389.92 rows=48330876 width=111)                      │
│               Sort Key: dat2.id, ((dat2.dt - 1))                                              │
│               ->  Seq Scan on mydat dat2  (cost=0.00..982694.76 rows=48330876 width=111)      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Out of curiosity, here is a naive join of `mydat` with itself:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mydat AS dat1
  JOIN mydat AS dat2
    ON dat1.id = dat2.id
   AND dat1.dt = dat2.dt;
```

The query plan is similar:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                          QUERY PLAN                                           │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Merge Join  (cost=19919125.46..27878413.41 rows=427198811 width=222)                          │
│   Merge Cond: ((dat1.id = dat2.id) AND (dat1.dt = dat2.dt))                                   │
│   ->  Sort  (cost=9959562.73..10080389.92 rows=48330876 width=111)                            │
│         Sort Key: dat1.id, dat1.dt                                                            │
│         ->  Seq Scan on act_2003q1 dat1  (cost=0.00..982694.76 rows=48330876 width=111)       │
│   ->  Materialize  (cost=9959562.73..10201217.11 rows=48330876 width=111)                     │
│         ->  Sort  (cost=9959562.73..10080389.92 rows=48330876 width=111)                      │
│               Sort Key: dat2.id, dat2.dt                                                      │
│               ->  Seq Scan on act_2003q1 dat2  (cost=0.00..982694.76 rows=48330876 width=111) │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Such a query plan puzzled me. Here, my question is what is the best practice for these use-cases? Thanks.

The above queries are tested on both `Postgresql 9.5.3` on Windows and `9.4.6` on Linux: the results are similar.

---

Given @Erwin's suggestion, the lag over a window function is tested, and the result is much better than the initial merge-join approach: `511524ms` to finish the query. As Erwin pointed out, the query is not exactly the same as the original one. Especially if there are gaps in the `dt` field, then some records would be unwanted.

This is an example I found that table partition is beneficial since the dataset I work with is larger than the example given above. The bottom-line of the problem is that postgresql uses disk to sort all records, and does not use index at all for both queries.

Comment: Instead of `select * ...` try `select id, dt ...`

Comment: @Hogan, just tried, and no difference. Still merge join with sort.

Comment: `My goal is to join each record and its next one for each id`. That's not a goal, that's an implementation detail. What is your actual goal? And please *always* include your version of Postgres.

Comment: The goal is rephrased, and PostgreSQL versions are added now...

Answer (score 2):

If you actual goal is to have the previous value of `data` in each resulting row, then use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT *, lag(data) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS last_data
FROM   mydat;
```

The difference: rows for which there is no predecessor are still included. You may or may not want that. To exclude, use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, lag(data) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS last_data
   FROM   mydat
   ) t
WHERE  last_data IS NOT NULL;
```

The remaining corner case was this: If `data` can be NULL, we cannot tell the difference between a genuine NULL value and 'not found'. So use a different *impossible* default value for the "not found" case like demonstrated:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, lag(data, 1, '-infinity') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS last_data
   FROM   mydat
   ) t
WHERE  last_data IS DISTINCT FROM '-infinity';
```

Each of these queries only needs a ***single* sequential scan**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will do a thorough tests then report back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know postgresql that well but this would be magic on db2 and mssql

```
WITH get_em as
( SELECT id, dt
  FROM mydat AS dat1
  JOIN mydat AS dat2
    ON dat1.id = dat2.id
   AND dat1.dt = dat2.dt - 1
)
select mydat.*
from mydat
join get_em on ON mydat.id = get_em.id AND mydat.dt = get_em.dt
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just tried out the code, yet it didn't work.

Comment: @opensrc - ok I can't help if you don't tell me more.